# jquery post an array to php

Tags: jquery, arrays

Im trying to POST 2 arrays with jquery and ajax.
Here are my 2 arrays: myArray1[id] , myArray2[id] (id can take values from 0 to a variable Num-1)
so for example i can access them with a simple For loop like this

```
for(id=0; id<Num; id++){
 console.log(myArray1[id]);
 console.log(myArray2[id]);
  }
```

Is it possible when i trigger an event to POST all the contect of these 2 tables with ajax to a php? If there was not tables and just variables(myArray1 and myArray2) i would be doing something like this:

```
data : "myArray1ID"+ id + "=" + (myArray1) + "&" +"myArray2ID" + id + "=" + (myArray2)
```

So can i do something like this in order to POST the arrays, maybe with a For loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(
  url, 
  {myArray1ID: myArray1, myArray2ID: myArray2},
  function() {
    // success function
  }
)
```

If your data chunk it huge then try to make a string and send it like `{data: YOUR_QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to imagine the data is so large that you have to break it up into multiple requests.  Send 'em all at once is a lot saner.

Comment: Yes but its a POST so i think i wont have problem to send them with one request. My problem to your answer is that i want to send them with the format that ive wrote in the data: . With your code i wont be able to send all the array content and with the format that i wont. So maybe is better to make a very big string with the array values and names and send this string??

Comment: @lucky13 yup, if your data chunk it huge then try to make a string and send it like {data: YOUR_QUERY_STRING}